# proof some inequality by induction

Tags: inequality, induction

I got to proof the following in-equality by induction for an assignment but having a hard time.

$$
\frac{2n}{(a+b)^n} \leq \frac{1}{a^n} + \frac{1}{b^n}
$$
$a,b > 0$

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Can you prove the base case? The induction step? Do you have any ideas for either?

Comment: What you do is assume it's true for some $n$ and then show it's true for $n+1$. So replace $n$ with $n+1$ in the expression $\frac{2n}{(a+b)^n}$, and use the fact that you're assuming $\frac{2n}{(a+b)^n} \leq \frac{1}{a^n} + \frac{1}{b^n}$

Comment: i've tried that but ended up with $$
\frac{2k}{(a+b)^k} \leq \frac{a}{bb^k} + \frac{b}{aa^k}
$$ and i dont know how to continue from here

Answer (score 0):

Jensens inequality for the convex function $f(x)=x^{-n}$ tells us that
$$
\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^{-n}=f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)\le\frac{f(a)+f(b)}2=\frac{a^{-n}+b^{-n}}2
$$
which transforms to
$$
\frac{2^{n+1}}{(a+b)^n}\le\frac1{a^n}+\frac1{b^n}
$$
Hence you only need to show that $2n\le 2^{n+1}$.

---

If you can't use Jensens inequality or the chain of mean inequalities, then at least you now that there is lots of space for very sloppy estimates in intermediate steps.